Change credentials for "Extract data" data source in Looker Studio
We have reports that use "Extract data" data sources. Those have been created by an individual user that will leave the company (the account is still active). How can we change the credentials used for the data source?
The normal way would be to edit the data source and click on the name next to "Data credentials". But when I try to do that for the "Extract data" data sources it says "This data source can only use viewers credentials because of a policy on your organisation.".

This however doesn't seem to be true: When I log in with a different user (Editor), I still see the name of the old employee next to "Data credentials" - not the name of the currently logged in user, as you would expect if viewers credentials would really be used.
Does anybody now if there is really such a policy and which one it might be - or what else we can do (short of creating a new data source for all of our reports).
Any hints are greatly appreciated!
